# Rmarkdown toc for tabbed content (only showing corresponding headings)

Tags: r, tabs, r-markdown, tableofcontents

I want to display a floating table of contents in a rmarkdown document which has tabbed content. I only want to show the headings of the current tab selected.

This is a minimal code example:

```
---
title: "Test"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
---

# Tabbed content {.tabset}

## Tab 1

### Tab 1 - Heading 1

## Tab 2

### Tab 2 - Heading 1

## {- .leave-tabset}
```

This is what the output looks like:

[image: table of contents with tabbed content]

I want to show only the corresponding headings in the toc when the respective tab is selected (so "Tab 1 - Heading 1" when Tab 1 is selected and "Tab 2 - Heading 1" when Tab 2 is selected).

I found a suggested solution with Javascript, which unfortunately didn't work in my case: [solution including Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54803465/rmarkdown-is-it-possible-to-display-the-toc-of-the-current-tab-only-in-a-tabse)

Comment: I found a solution which works fine for my data although it is not exactly what I was looking for originally. I now created a rmarkdown website with a YAML header instead of tabs. So each site builds the toc individually now. For further information on rmarkdown websites: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-13.html

Answer (score 0):

This works for me if you put your header as follow:

```
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    includes:
      in_header: header.html
    css: style.css
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 1
```

With toc_depth = 1 it should only show Level 1 in the toc

Which I now realise does not answer your question. I'm not sure how to only show in toc what is currently being selected. I would be tempted to say : what is the point of the toc if it shows only what is currently selected, and not the other sections you might want to navigate, or know about their existence?